# Generate a random word from an array and then print it to the console log in a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, console

I am creating hangman in javascript and I have (I think) successfully generated a random word from an array in a function, to check if it works I am trying to print the generated word in to the console but it doesn't seem to be working here's my code for the function

```
    var word = function() //Random word is genereated from an array for the user to guess
{
  GameWordArray = new Array(7);
  GameWordArray[0] = "monitor";
  GameWordArray[1] = "program";
  GameWordArray[2] = "application";
  GameWordArray[3] = "keyboard";
  GameWordArray[4] = "javascript";
  GameWordArray[5] = "gaming";
  GameWordArray[6] = "network";
  randno = Math.floor(Math.random() * GameWordArray.length);
  document.write(GameWordArray[randno]);
  console.log(word);
}
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Creating your random word in that manner is kind of painful as you create a new array of the words each time you call the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/k6Qxn/)

```
var words = ["monitor", "program", "application", "keyboard", "javascript", "gaming", "network"];

var word = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

console.log(word);

document.getElementById("word").textContent = word;
```

And to have it fit in directly with you present code:

```
var getRandomWord = function () {
    return words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using it this way:

```
var getRandomWord = (function () {
  var gameWordArray = [];
  gameWordArray.push("monitor");
  gameWordArray.push("program");
  gameWordArray.push("application");
  gameWordArray.push("keyboard");
  gameWordArray.push("javascript");
  gameWordArray.push("gaming");
  gameWordArray.push("network");
  return function () {
    var randNum, finalWord;
    randNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * gameWordArray.length);
    finalWord = gameWordArray[randNum];
    return finalWord;
  };
})();
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/bCEFA/1/

Instead of declaring an array with a predefined length, you might as well declare an empty one and add values to the end of it (with `.push()`). You could've also declared the array like:

```
var gameWordArray = ["monitor", "program", ...];
```

You were trying to print `word` (which I renamed to `getRandomWord`), which was/is a function. You probably meant to use `console.log(gameWordArray[randno])`, which should work.

Comment: Thanks but when I put this in place of my original code and try and run it, it gives me a syntax error elsewhere in the code

It gives me this error on this line of code;

Error detected: syntax error (#86) 
Error at or around line number 86

document.getElementById("button").onclick = guessButtonClicked;

Comment: @OwenBrain Don't you think it would be helpful to provide the actual error or where the syntax error is referring to?

Comment: Yeah I tried, sorry if it didn't come through properly I am new to this site, thanks

Answer (score 0):

That's what helped me to avoid duplicate alt tags for my online shop:

```
var items = ['word1', 'word2', 'word3'];
var item = items[Math.floor(Math.random() * items.length)];
```

I even doubled it and had a much more range on unique alt tags:

```
var items2 = ['word4', 'word5', 'word6'];
var item2 = items2[Math.floor(Math.random() * items2.length)];
```

And in the end it looked like this for my alt-tags on my product gallery thumbnails:

```
markup += '<div class="product-image-thumbnail"><img alt="' + alt + ' ' + item + ' ' + item2 + '" title="' + title + '" src="' + image + '" /></div>';
```